# Why has my orange tree turned yellow and stopped bearing fruit?

Tags: diagnosis, fruit-trees, citrus

I live in Spain, and this year my orange tree has turned yellow all over, with no flowers or fruit. What could it be? I have taken a picture.

[image]

Comment: How long have you had the tree and can you check underneath the leaves, see if there's anything there that shouldn't be

Comment: Bottom of leaves clear and less mottled than top. We moved into the house 3 years ago tree was in full fruit and green. Then downhill since then. When you look at the leaves from underneath the veins seem slightly greener than the rest thanks

Comment: Couple more questions - have you used weedkiller in the area in the last year? How long have those stones been in place? And what's your weather been like this autumn/winter- warmer than usual and very wet? Or colder than usual and very dry?

Comment: It looks like you have a stone mulch in place which means it's going to stop any organic matter settling and feeding the tree roots.  When did you last apply a citrus fertilizer?

Answer (score 5):

As you may know, plants can be victim of different kinds of affections :

- Nutrients deficiency
- Parasits assaults
- Meteorological perturbations

First of all, you should check for parasits, **even if I don't think the leaf color is caused by a predator or a disease**. Return a leaf, better with a magnifying glass, and try to spot living / moving creatures. For example, *aphids* look loke little black dots and make leaves sticky.

Secondly, find information about citrus culture in your specific region (if you live in Andalousia or in Galicia, climate change from oceanic to mediterranean). **Yellow but not dry leaves** are often caused by too wet soil (bad water extraction, too much rain...).

At last, check for agrum tree deficiencies. **In my opinion, this is a nitrogen deficiency**. Treat with some grow fertilizer or, if you prefer more natural way, **ashes, nettle manure or garden compost**. [This link](https://extension.umd.edu/hgic/nutrient-deficiency-trees-and-shrubs) can give you an idea on how to diagnosis affliction, but you should find something more accurate for your citrus.

Comment: We are in Murcia a dry region and major citrus fruit centre. Def no parasites on close inspection if anything i have under watered thanks

Comment: Some soils doesn't drain water correctly, resulting in asphxing accumulation. And again, it may need some fertilizer.